# How to install a Windows XP folder over the existing Windows XP

Tags: windows-xp, installation

My computer doesn't have partitions on the hard drive and the existing install of Windows XP was corrupted.

I tried all of the possible solutions that I found. My last option is to install the folder of Windows XP in the same hard drive, but I don't know the procedure.

Comment: Do you have the Windows XP installation CD?

Comment: Yes, ihave Window XP CD.

Answer (score 0):

One Bing search later for "how to parallel install windows xp" and I get the following:

TechNet article for windows 2000 (which XP is based off of)
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/266465

Random computer info page. Has good scrren caps:
http://123pcworld.com/Computer-Tips-and-Tricks/1/How-to-do-a-parallel-install-in-Windows-XP.html

Microsoft Support page on reinstalling windows. Lots of text, no pics:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/978788

Hope this helps